# how to slowdown postgresql server?

Tags: database, hibernate, postgresql, spring-jdbc, postgresql-9.4

I am trying to reproduce a customer issue , and to prove my hypootheis of whats happening, i need the slow down the postgres. I strongly feel my application shoots up cpu usage when db query becomes very slow. Is there is a way to slow down my postgres query. 
I have tried reducing to the following

- Shared Buffer = 64kB
- Work_mem = 64kB
- max_connection=8

Also I am currently using hibernate 3.0 , does anyone know about any performance issue of hibernate on this version

Comment: Why do you think that arbitrarily "slowing" down Postgres would at all represent the scenario that your customer is dealing with? You should troubleshoot and find the reason why it is slow for them.

Comment: If you [lock](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-lock.html) the table which the application is trying to access, then the query will hang until the lock is released

Answer (score 1):

I would create a VM with VirtualBox, set up your PostgreSQL server on it, and set a low bandwidth limit on the VDI to simulate a really slow disk. I'd also set the memory settings low like you did so the RAM isn't used for caching and give the VM minimal RAM so it doesn't do disk caching.